# UWSGI Flask SQLAlchemy Intermittent PostgreSQL errors with "WARNING: there is already a transaction in progress"

Tags: postgresql, flask, sqlalchemy, uwsgi

In my UWSGI Flask application I'm getting intermittent errors like the following :

- `DatabaseError: (psycopg2.DatabaseError) error with no message from the libpq`
- `ResourceClosedError: This result object does not return rows. It has been closed automatically.`
- `NoSuchColumnError: "Could not locate column in row for column 'my_table.my_column_name_that_exists'"`
- `DatabaseError: (psycopg2.DatabaseError) insufficient data in "D" message...lost synchronization with server: got message type "2", length 740303471`

In my postgresql log I see: `WARNING:  there is already a transaction in progress`

Refreshing the web page in flask usually resolves the error.

Here are the steps I take to reproduce the error:

1. stop the application
2. `sudo service postgresql restart`
3. start the application
4. navigate to a web page in my flask app that does several simultaneous queries

   - expected behavior: no database errors logged
   - actual behavior: one or more of the errors listed above occur

I tried increasing the verbosity of postgresql logging and what appears to be inappropriate sharing of virtual transactions, e.g. following shows all log entries with virtual transaction `2/53` and corresponds to the above errors:

```
process 8548 session 5901589a.2164 vtransaction 2/53 LOG:  statement: BEGIN
process 8548 session 5901589a.2164 vtransaction 2/53 LOG:  statement: SELECT 1
process 8548 session 5901589a.2164 vtransaction 2/53 LOG:  statement: SELECT my_table.id AS my_table_id, ... 
    FROM my_table 
    WHERE my_table.id = 'my_id' 
     LIMIT 1
process 8548 session 5901589a.2164 vtransaction 2/53 LOG:  statement: BEGIN
process 8548 session 5901589a.2164 vtransaction 2/53 WARNING:  there is already a transaction in progress
process 8548 session 5901589a.2164 vtransaction 2/53 LOG:  statement: SELECT 1
process 8548 session 5901589a.2164 vtransaction 2/53 LOG:  statement: SELECT my_other_table.id AS my_other_table_id, ...
    FROM my_other_table
    WHERE 'my_other_id' = my_other_table.id
process 8548 session 5901589a.2164 vtransaction 2/53 LOG:  statement: SELECT my_table.id AS my_table_id, ... 
    FROM my_table 
    WHERE my_table.id = 'my_id' 
     LIMIT 1
process 8548 session 5901589a.2164 vtransaction 2/53 LOG:  statement: ROLLBACK
```

Comment: You're most likely using the same connection across threads. What kind of threading are you doing?

Comment: The flask app is run by uwsgi.  In the `uwsgi.ini` I have `processes=8` and `threads=1`

Comment: Are you using pre-fork? If so, are you issuing SQL before you fork?

Comment: As far as I can tell there is no forking, but when I changed the `uwsgi.ini` `processes=1` the error is no longer occurring so we must be getting closer.

Comment: Of course there's forking. That's the way of getting multiple processes on posix systems. When that forking happens is of concern. Try turning on [lazy-apps](http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/articles/TheArtOfGracefulReloading.html#preforking-vs-lazy-apps-vs-lazy).

Comment: Turning on lazy-apps resolved the errors

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These errors are symptoms of database connections being shared incorrectly by multiple threads or processes.

By default, uwsgi forks the process after the application is created in the wsgi-file.  If the application creation creates database connections that may be re-used, you will likely end up with forked processes having corrupt database state.  To resolve this in uwsgi there are options:

1. do not create database connections until after the application is created, **OR**
2. call uwsgi with the `--lazy-apps` option, which changes uwsgi to fork before the application is created

There are negative performance consequences to `lazy-apps` mode (see [preforking vs lazy-apps vs lazy](http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/articles/TheArtOfGracefulReloading.html#preforking-vs-lazy-apps-vs-lazy)), so avoiding database usage during app creation is generally the better option.

Thanks univerio for explaining this in the comments.